# Google App Engine won't put object on server, but works on local version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm getting the following error on Google App Engine when I attempt to post a image (blob) and some other data to the datastore through a Web form. The code works on my local machine, but not when I upload to the GAE environment. :

```
<type 'str'> has type <type 'str'>, but expected one of: int, long, bool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~mygrajj/1.371507856337629790/main.py", line 123, in post
    car.put()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3232, in _put
    return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 748, in put
    key = yield self._put_batcher.add(entity, options)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 371, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.send(val)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 280, in _put_tasklet
    keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1574, in async_put
    pbs = [self.__adapter.entity_to_pb(entity) for entity in entities]
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 570, in entity_to_pb
    pb = ent._to_pb()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2945, in _to_pb
    prop._serialize(self, pb, projection=self._projection)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1297, in _serialize
    p.set_multiple(self._repeated or parent_repeated)
  File "cpp_message.pyx", line 124, in cpp_message.SetScalarAccessors.Setter (third_party/apphosting/python/protobuf/proto1/cpp_message.cc:2229)
TypeError: <type 'str'> has type <type 'str'>, but expected one of: int, long, bool
```

When trying to execute the following code:

```
class AddCar(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler, webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        car = Car()
        if self.get_uploads('file'):
            upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
            blob_info = upload_files[0]
            car.CarBlobKey = blob_info.key()
            car.CarImageServingURL.append(images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key()))
        car.CarYear = self.request.get('modelyear0')+self.request.get('modelyear1')+self.request.get('modelyear2')
        car.CarMake = self.request.get('makeField')
        car.CarModel = self.request.get('modelField')
        car.CarPosterGrajjStatus = self.request.get('which_grajj')
        if users.get_current_user():
            car.CarPoster = users.get_current_user()
        car.put()
        #grajj_query = Car.query()
        #cars = grajj_query.fetch(100)
        self.redirect('/mygrajj.html')
```

Here's my model:

```
class Car(ndb.Model):
    # Car class contains data on a prototype car
    CarYear = ndb.StringProperty()
    CarMake = ndb.StringProperty()
    CarModel = ndb.StringProperty()
    CarPoster = ndb.UserProperty()
    CarPosted = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add="true")
    CarPosterGrajjStatus = ndb.StringProperty()
    CarBlobKey = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(indexed="false")
    CarImageServingURL = ndb.StringProperty(indexed="false", repeated="true")
```

The code works on my local machine, but not when it's deployed

Comment: what does the definition for the model `Car` look like?

Comment: `class Car(ndb.Model):
    # Car class contains data on a prototype car
    CarYear = ndb.StringProperty()
    CarMake = ndb.StringProperty()
    CarModel = ndb.StringProperty()
    CarPoster = ndb.UserProperty()
    CarPosted = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add="true")
    CarPosterGrajjStatus = ndb.StringProperty()
    CarBlobKey = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(indexed="false")
    CarImageServingURL = ndb.StringProperty(indexed="false", repeated="true")`

Comment: Sorry that's a little messy in comments, but the model is in the original post, too.

Answer (score 0):

How about drop the blob and isolate where the problem is.

Comment: So this is the line that appears to be evil: car.CarImageServingURL.append(images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key()))

Comment: With that line in, it breaks. With the line gone, it works. Brain hurts

Answer (score 0):

I think this line will reference a `NoneType` since `CarImageServingURL` does not have a default value.

```
car.CarImageServingURL.append(images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key()))
```

You could rewrite it as

```
car.CarImageServingURL = images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key())
```

Or try changing the definition to have a default:

```
CarImageServingURL = ndb.StringProperty(indexed="false", repeated="true", default="")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change all the parameter to Boolean

```
class Car(ndb.Model):
  # Car class contains data on a prototype car
  CarYear = ndb.StringProperty()
  CarMake = ndb.StringProperty()
  CarModel = ndb.StringProperty()
  CarPoster = ndb.UserProperty()
  CarPosted = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add="true")
  CarPosterGrajjStatus = ndb.StringProperty()
  CarBlobKey = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(indexed="false")
  CarImageServingURL = ndb.StringProperty(indexed="false", repeated="true")

auto_now_add=True
indexed=False
repeated=True
```

ommit the ""